# UML to Java code: abstract class, simple association, methods

Tags: java, uml

I'm going through some questions from 2019 class on information systems. My own exam is coming this week. 
The question is to roughly translate this UML diagram into a Java code, it does not have to be a part of workable code, more of a general idea. Am I on the right track? What have I done wrong in my code sketch?

```
abstract public class Person {
   public String name; // explicit field
   private String address; // explicit field
   private String phone; //explicit field
   // assuming some methods for creating a record
   // a getter and setter for name, address and phone
}

public class GeneralPractitioner extends Person {

   private String medicalID; //explicit field, either private or protected
   private <Arraylist> Patient patient; // GeneralPractitioner – Patient 

   //getter and setter methods for medicalID

   public addPatient(Patient patient) {
       //… code implementation 
   }
}

public class Patient extends Person {

   private String patientID; //explict field

   private Arraylist <medicalRecord> medicalrecord; //assuming a class for a medical record
   private GeneralPractitioner generalPractitioner; // Patiend – GeneralPractitioner 0..* 1..1
   // getter and setter for patient id

   public addRecord(medicalRecord) {
     //…
   }
}
```

[image: UML diagram]

Comment: Hello, you seem to be on the right track, however, your code fails to compile due to multiple syntax issues.  For example, you should have declared list of patients as `List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();`, methods `addPatient / addMedicalRecord` should be declared as `void` if they don't return anything, etc.  Code formatting and naming conventions need to be improved too.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helps, one question though - where would be the place to declare the list of patients, in one of the classes or when I start writing main()?

Comment: By this design, each `GeneralPractitioner` _has_ a `List<Patient> patients`, and each `Patient` has a reference to its `GeneralPractitioner` thus forming _one-to-many/many-to-one_ bidirectional relationship.  Similarly, each Patient _has a_ `List<MedicalRecord> records`.  So in `main()` method you should be creating instances of `GP` and `Patient` and then use `GP` method `addPatient`